# i want to select a randomly data using php

Tags: php

I need help in selecting a random data from the table

Let's suppose There are 10 columns in my table but i want that if I hit the query sometime it will bring all data and sometime it will bring data only from 1 column and some time from the no 1 and no 2 column

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

```
function selectAllInventoriesINGroup($conn,$groupname,$import_id)
{

  $cgstSgst = explode('-', $groupname);
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM stockitems WHERE generalid = '$import_id' AND cgst = '$cgstSgst[0]' AND sgst = '$cgstSgst[1]' ORDER BY RAND()";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  $jsonxx = mysqli_fetch_all ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

  return $jsonxx ;
}
```

I have tested this but it fetch the all the data from the database

```
<?php
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM stockitems WHERE generalid = '$import_id' AND cgst = '$cgstSgst[0]' AND sgst = '$cgstSgst[1]' ORDER BY RAND()";
?>
```

Comment: you're open to SQL injection. You should address imminently

Comment: So you want to randomly select columns? Randomly which ones and how many?

Comment: Check this example[MySQL Select Random Records: Examples](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/tryit/query/mysql-select-random/#2)

Comment: sometimes It may select only one column and sometime it can 2 or 3 column from the table

Comment: Not like this When I execute the query Sometime it can fetch 1 column and on next execution it will 2 column or the 3 column from the table

Comment: Sounds like you are doing things wrong to begin with, by having what is essentially the same data (regarding the meaning, not the actual specific value) spread horizontally over multiple columns - instead of storing it properly _normalized_.

Comment: Your example will fetch only 1 column If i increase the limit then it will fetch the column according the limit but I don't want the limit.                                                      I want that server will randomly shows the column sometime 1 column and sometime 2  or 3 column as like that on every execution of the query It will vary the number of column